# CSS selector only works if <tag>has contents</tag>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to assign a style to a HTML element - but only in the event that the tag has some contents set.

Is this possible using pure CSS? Ideally I would like to avoid JS or server-side changes to the structure of the HTML itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content aware CSS - apply style only if content is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063446/content-aware-css-apply-style-only-if-content-is-available)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSS3 has an [`:empty` pseudo -class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo).

I can't see any way of doing this in pure CSS2.1.

Comment: Didn't realise the :empty pseudo-class existed... nice one :-) +1

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with CSS3 by combining the [`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) and [`:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo) pseudo-classes.  For browsers that don't support both you'll need to use JS or a server-side solution.

```
div:not(:empty) { background-color:blue; }
```