# Content aware CSS - apply style only if content is available

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a css style be aware of whether the element it is being applied to has some sort of content or not? I am currently using tables (forced to since the end user uses cms to create pages) with a css for each cell, as so

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="someClass">Test value 1</td>
    <td class="someClass">Test value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="someClass">Test value 3</td>
    <td class="someClass"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As displayed, there is the chance that a table cell is left empty. Is there a way to make "someClass" aware of this and not apply the style to this cell?

I am sure there is some js hack I could apply, but I wonder if it is possible with pure css. Long shot?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of style do you want? You have `empty-cells:hide;` which will hide the borders of a cell.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Simply use the `:empty` pseudo-class like so:

```
td.someClass:not(:empty) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

As Petr Marek mentions it's not very reliable as a cross-browser solution, so if you *must* support older browsers (IE8 and older) you *will* need JS (which you can probably figure out yourself). Otherwise, the above CSS rule will work just fine.

You can find the browser compatibility of `:not()` and `:empty` [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Comment: 11 years later and still find this very useful!

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I can think of that relates to your question is psuedo-classes, such as     empty.
Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .cell:not(:empty) {
        background-color: red;    
      }
      .cell:empty {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table><tBody>
      <tr><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell">Not empty</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="cell">Not empty</td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
    </tBody></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In modern browsers, you will see that empty cells are blue and cells with content are red.
The key here is the first line of CSS, .cell:not(:empty). This applies the CSS if the element does not have the psuedo-class :empty applied.

Answer (score 2):

No, with pure **cross-browser** css it is not. You will have to edit their cms or use javascript.

Comment: Technically, this answer is true. However, not many people use browsers that lack [basic support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) for `:not` anymore.