# CSS padding before content

Tags: html, css

I want to include some padding after the `before` in a button, but only if there is also text content.  So given

```
<button class="btn-action"></button>
```

The css would be

```
.btn-action:before {
    content: "X";
}
```

and given

```
<button class="btn-action">Text</button>
```

the css would be

```
.btn-action:before {
    content: "X";
    padding-right: 0.35em;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to write a single css class that handles both cases.  If I was dealing with real elements I could probably use a selector such as:

```
.btn-action:before + content {
    padding-right: 0.35em;
}
```

but AFAIK this can't be done.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content aware CSS - apply style only if content is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063446/content-aware-css-apply-style-only-if-content-is-available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:empty` selector.

CSS:

```
.btn-action:empty:before {
    padding:0;
}
.btn-action:before {
    content:"X";
    padding-right: 0.35em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/70vkfmsd/2/

Updated the padding.

**Note:** Make sure that there is no white-space in the empty button for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, although FWIW it looks like it is not necessary to repeat the `content`.

Comment: Yeah, you can optimize it. I just wanted to show working of :empty selector.