# Hide text boxes if it does not contain data

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use javascript to hide a table if there is no data present. I am using Powershell to grab data from a spreadsheet; however, if there is no data in the spreadsheet the table is not required.

In a nutshell, if the td with an id of "hide if empty" does not contain any data can the div with div with id "sampleDIV" or the table with id "Tabletest" not be visible?

Is this possible?

Thank you :)

```html
<div id="SampleDIV">
  <table id="TableTest">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Data:</b></td>
        <td id="hide if empty"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Am I doing something really silly?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language ="javascript">
if (document.getElementById("hideifempty").innerHTML === "") {
  document.getElementById("SampleDIV").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<div id="SampleDIV">
  <table id="TableTest">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Data:</b></td>
        <td id="hideifempty"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>If you can see this it didn't hide</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all, id names cant have spaces. And yes you can do this with jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content aware CSS - apply style only if content is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063446/content-aware-css-apply-style-only-if-content-is-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (document.getElementById("hideifempty").innerHTML === "") {
  document.getElementById("SampleDIV").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="SampleDIV">
  <table id="TableTest">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Data:</b></td>
        <td id="hideifempty"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>If you can see this it didn't hide</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You may want to use `.innerHTML.trim() === ""` - up to you depending on whether you define an element with nothing but whitespace as "empty".

Note: Element IDs are not supposed to contain spaces (although that may work in some browsers), so I've changed the id to `"hideifempty"`.

**EDIT:** Note that the above JS would need to be in a `<script>` element that is *after* the `<div>` in question, so e.g., you could follow the reasonably standard practice of putting scripts immediately before the closing `</body>` tag. Or you could wrap the above `if` statement in an `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` handler. Otherwise the JS will run before the browser has parsed the div and table.

Comment: Am I doing something really silly? 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script language ="javascript">
if (document.getElementById("hideifempty").innerHTML === "") {
  document.getElementById("SampleDIV").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<div id="SampleDIV">
  <table id="TableTest">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Data:</b></td>
        <td id="hideifempty"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>If you can see this it didn't hide</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I've added a note about where to include the JS.

Comment: You're awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

you try:

```
  $('#TableTest tr').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).hide();
});​
```

or you can use css:

```
tr td:empty {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;

}
td:not(:empty) ~ td:empty{
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}​
```

​

Comment: The question asked to hide either the whole div or the whole table, not hide individual empty rows.

Comment: The JavaScript will hide the rows with empty columns and the CSS will hide only the empty columns. The OP wants to hide the entire table when a specific column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is and here is how you can do that

```js
if(document.querySelector("#hideIfEmpty").innerHTML.trim() == ""){
   document.querySelector("#SampleDIV").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="SampleDIV">
  <table id="TableTest">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Data:</b></td>
        <td id="hideIfEmpty"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You should probably add some checks to make sure the elements with the IDs `hideIfEmpty` and `SampleDIV` exist to prevent errors. Also, an element's ID can't contain spaces, that is why I've changed `hide if empty` to `hideIfEmpty`.